# Single YouTube video does not play in IE10, Flash 12.0.0.38

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer, youtube, flash-player

A Windows 7 PC with IE8 would not play [a YouTube video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ObbpK_r5Czg).

The video player loads, and the progress meter increases to show it is loading the movie in the background, but clicking the play button will not start the movie. Other movies are playing fine.

The Flash Player version was at 11, so I upgraded the Flash Player to 12.0.0.38.  This did not fix the issue.

I upgraded Windows 7 to Service Pack 1, and Internet Explorer to version 10.  This did not fix the issue.

I upgraded to IE11 without a change.

We have Kaspersky End Point Security 8 installed in this corporate environment.

I can play the video in IE10 on another Windows 7 PC in the same office.

Any thoughts?

Comment: When you say it does not play do you mean you see a blank box where the video player should be, is the video constantly loading etc? Are there any error messages?

Comment: Sorry, I should of written that into the question.  The video player loads, and the progress meter increases to show it is loading the movie in the background, but clicking the play button will not start the movie.

Other movies are fine.

Comment: Have you tried resetting the Internet Explorer settings by going to Internet Options -> Advanced -> Reset...?

Comment: I tried that in IE8, but not in IE10.

Comment: You could try reinstalling Flash or using the Youtube HTML5 player https://www.youtube.com/html5

Comment: We tried re-installing Flash with no success.  The HTML5 player did not work either.

Comment: I tried resetting IE settings in IE10 (Internet Options -> Advanced -> Reset) without success.

Comment: YouTube will soon stop supporting IE10, so you should try it in a newer version.

Comment: Is it possible to try another browser to isolate it to Internet Explorer?

Comment: FYI, latest Flash Player version is **12.0.0.44** right now. [Source](http://www.adobe.com/software/flash/about/)

Comment: @Steve Does it play in any other browser in your system?

Comment: It doesn't work in Firefox either with Flash 12.0.0.44.  However, if I log in to her computer, it works in both IE10 and Firefox for me, so it is related to her user profile.

Comment: Ok - I see two possibilities: First: Flash Settings are stored on a per User-basis, try to reset these Settings (you can delete the Adobe Settings folder, or use the Settings-Manager inside Flash)

Comment: Otherwise if you say it is in a company and only one Video - could it possibly be, the video triggers some URL-Filter, which is set for her?

Comment: Close all browsers, then open the Flash Player control panel applet. Select the Advanced tab and delete all stored data. Next clear all browser cache/temporary files and see if the issue persists.

Comment: If you haven't done so already, I'd suggest to give Chrome a try, since it doesn't use the flash installed on your computer but a built-in version that is compiled with Chrome.

Comment: @and31415: I tried this but unfortunately it made no difference.

Comment: @EliadTech: Unfortunately we are operating within an SOE, and Chrome is not allowed.

Comment: @Steve Latest Flash Player version is **12.0.0.70** now, make sure it's updated. It might not make any difference, but it wouldn't hurt anyway. Try creating a new standard user account, and see whether you can reproduce the issue there. Something else you can try: press Win+R, type `OptionalFeatures.exe`, and press Enter; locate Internet Explorer in the list, and disable it. Restart Windows to apply the changes, then repeat the same steps, and enable it again. Restart when done.

Answer (score 1):

See if switching to [Compatibility View](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/internet-explorer/use-compatibility-view#ie=ie-11) fixes the problem.
From the Microsoft Support site:

> To add a site to the Compatibility View list
>
> 1. Open the desktop, and then tap or click the Internet Explorer icon on the taskbar.
> 2. Tap or click the Tools button Tools, and then tap or click Compatibility View settings.
> 3. Under Add this website, enter the URL of the site you want to add to the list, and then tap or click Add.

If that don't work for you, check out the [YouTube HTML5 Player](http://www.youtube.com/html5).
It supports Internet Explorer.

If none of these solutions work, I would seriously recommend switching to a different browser, such as [Firefox](http://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/) or [Google Chrome](https://www.google.com/chrome/).

Comment: It doesn't work in Firefox either.  However, if I log in to her computer, it works in both IE10 and Firefox, so it is user profile related.

Comment: So you _have_ tried the [YouTube HTML5 Player](http://www.youtube.com/html5) _and_ [Compatibility View](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/internet-explorer/use-compatibility-view#ie=ie-11)?

Comment: Sorry.  Yes I have tried both of those.

Comment: Is your account an administrator?

Comment: Yes, my account is an administrator.

Answer (score 0):

If it's not like bobberson12 said, you can make **another account** (make administrator account) then try IE

If nothing changed try to **download flash player again** from Adobe (maybe your download got corrupted) then install it

If nothing changed you may stop add-ons or *reset IE*.

If nothing happens reinstall the flash file that you latest download

If *still* nothing changed, that may mean you have bad/corrupted Windows install.

See this on [resetting Internet Explorer](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/internet-explorer/reset-ie-settings#ie=ie-11).